# Xcode: Displaying Data in Tables

Tags: ios, tableview

Hello I am relatively new to the programming scene and have been using lynda.com to learn the skill and practice on small projects. I followed the instructors guidance to the letter, but our results are quite different. I want the "name" string of my course in my NSMutable Array to appear as the titles of the cells in my table but when I load the app nothing appears. Help a clueless kid out please!

here is the code for my class, the implementation file just includes the synthesization for my properties

```
#import "Class.h"

@implementation Course

@synthesize name,teacher,room;

@end
```

and here is the code for my UITable view controller class

```
#import "ScheduleTableViewController.h"

@interface ScheduleTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ScheduleTableViewController

NSMutableArray *classes;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


NSMutableArray *classes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Course *class = [[Course alloc]init];
[class setName:@"AP Psychology"];
[class setRoom:@"E203"];
[class setTeacher:@"Juiliette Forbes"];
[classes addObject:class];

[class setName:@"AP Literature"];
[class setTeacher:@"Kristen Holtz"];
[class setRoom:@"E207"];
[classes addObject:class];

[class setName:@"AP Physics"];
[class setTeacher:@"Peter Dalby"];
[class setRoom:@"D205"];
[classes addObject:class];

[super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{


return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [classes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ClassCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
             }
Course *current = [classes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[current name]];

return cell;
}
```

Any help will be well appreciated and hopefully I can keep up with any of the lingo

Comment: This part of your code doesn't look right. `#import "Class.h"

@implementation Course

@synthesize name,teacher,room;

@end` import Class.h and implementation Course? Also, you need to set your table view's **data source**, apart from delegate.

Comment: Please remove the redeclaration datasource array classes from  viewdidLoad(), your code will work perfect.

Comment: the file is called class.h but I had to change the name of class from "class" because that was conflicting with some of the foundation coding so I changed it to "course". As for the redeclaration of the datasource I am afraid I don't actually know what that is is it possible you could highlight that for me? Sorry as I said I am kinda new

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you've correctly set the identifier for the table cell.

To do this, open up your storyboard editor and go to your table view. Click on the prototype cell and open up the Utilities pane. Check that "Identifier" is "ClassCell".

Next, make sure your ViewController is a UITableViewController and implements the UITableViewDelegate protocol. It's not clear if you've done this.

Your ScheduleTableViewController.h should be something like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScheduleTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
// code
@end
```

Also, I noticed this here:

```
NSMutableArray *classes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Course *class = [[Course alloc]init];
[class setName:@"AP Psychology"];
[class setRoom:@"E203"];
[class setTeacher:@"Juiliette Forbes"];
[classes addObject:class];

[class setName:@"AP Literature"];
[class setTeacher:@"Kristen Holtz"];
[class setRoom:@"E207"];
[classes addObject:class];

[class setName:@"AP Physics"];
[class setTeacher:@"Peter Dalby"];
[class setRoom:@"D205"];
[classes addObject:class];
```

Since *class is a pointer to a course object, you've only actually created one, then you keep editing its properties and re-adding it to the array. Create multiple class objects like so:

```
Course *class1 = [[Course alloc] init];
// set properties
Course *class2 = [[Course alloc] init];
// set properties
Course *class3 = [[Course alloc] init];
// set properties
[classes addObjects:class1, class2, class3, nil];
```

Comment: My reuse identifier is good and so is my delegate protocol. I think it has less to do with my array and more to do with my table as when I attempted to add text that wasn't from the array still nothing appearred. Thank you for the suggestion about the class pointer. I thought the same thing but the man in the video was able to do it with a single pointer reused over and over.

Comment: What Vinodh is referring to when he says not to redeclare your datasource array is that you have twice typed:

NSMutableArray *classes;

You only need to declare something once. Therefore, change the following line:

NSMutableArray *classes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
to:
classes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

(Edit: What this means is that your array is not filling with anything because it hasn't been initialised. Instead you've initialised another variable called the same thing.)